# Oval Shape in Overlay View in Xamarin

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I followed this [Blog](https://www.xamboy.com/2019/02/23/overlayview-in-xamarin-forms/) to add Overlay View on my Camera Preview.

In background, Camera Preview is opened, and on the top of it there is overlay outer rectangle (in Fuchsia color) and circle shape inside.

There are two shapes **Circle** & **Heart**. I want to add **Oval**.

I added Oval, but it didn't worked.

**OverlayView.cs**

```
public enum OverlayShape
    {
        Circle,
        Heart,
        Oval
    }
```

```
public static readonly BindableProperty ShapeProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
   propertyName: nameof(Shape),
   returnType: typeof(CameraOverlayShape),
   declaringType: typeof(CameraOverlayView),
   defaultValue: CameraOverlayShape.Oval,
   defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay);
```

**NativeOverlayView.cs**

```
OverlayShape overlayShape = OverlayShape.Oval;

public OverlayShape Shape
{
    get { return overlayShape; }
    set
    {
        overlayShape = value;
        Redraw();

    }
}
```

```
Paint paint = new Paint(PaintFlags.AntiAlias)
{
    Color = OverlayBackgroundColor,
    Alpha = (int)(255 * Opacity)
};

RectF outerRectangle = new RectF(0, 0, width, height);

osCanvas.DrawRect(outerRectangle, paint);
```

```
switch (Shape)
{
    case OverlayShape.Oval:
        osCanvas.DrawOval(outerRectangle, paint);

        break;
    default:
    
    // Code
    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code works on my side .

```
 case OverlayShape.Oval:
     shapeHeight = (float)(shapeHeight * 0.8);
     RectF rect = new RectF(width / 2- shapeWidth / 2, height / 2 - shapeHeight / 2, shapeWidth/2+ width/2 , shapeHeight/2+height/2);
     osCanvas.DrawOval(rect, paint);
     break;
```

[image]

Comment: Set shape as `Oval`  on OverlayView defined in MainPage.xaml .

Comment: No , actually it is oval , you can add a breakpoint to debug it . It is happening because the  width is the same as height , you can make them different .check my update code.